# how to open a powerpoint file that has been modified in c#

Tags: c#

i have a c# windows forms application that opens up a powerpoint file, now if i make a change to the powerpoint file and if my program is running it must automatically pick up the file that has been modified, or can i set like a timer to refresh the page so it will pick up the changes?

The following code works in opening a file.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var app = new PowerPoint.Application();
            var pres = app.Presentations;

            var file = pres.Open(@"C:\Pres1.pptx", MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
            PowerPoint.SlideShowSettings slideSetting = file.SlideShowSettings;
            slideSetting.Run();

            PowerPoint.SlideShowWindows slideShowWindows = app.SlideShowWindows;
            while (true)
            {
                if (slideShowWindows.Count <= 0)

                    break;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FileSystemWatcher` class to detect changes to that file ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Comment: if i watch a file for a change ,how do i call that file to be opened?